# Chronicle Queue: blockSize, index count and size guidance

Tags: java, chronicle, chronicle-queue

The ChronicleQueueBuilder interface (4.5) allows parameterisation of the queue file characteristics. By default I get 80mb files for daily rollover.

- Is there any guidance how one should use these values?
- What are the trade-offs? Can I optimize it to let an appender seek to an index quickly?
- If I know my average excerpt size and the average number
  of excerpts per period, can I choose these values to avoid resizing
  of the queue file during the day?

Comment: I suggest using `5.17.x` as this has Java 11 compatibility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you have a reason to change it I would leave it as it is. If you make the chunk size smaller it might use less space on windows though on linux it uses sparse files so it won't make a difference.

You could increase the chunk size to 1 GB or more however  if you are concerned about the cost of resizing I suggest calling the pretoucher() in another thread periodically to ensure there is always headroom.

Comment: How do I change the blockSize from default of max 16MB to a value higher than that in the code ? Any help is appreciated

Comment: @AnirudhKashyap The default is 64MB, you can call `ChronicleQueueBuilder.blockSize(128 << 20)` to change to 128 MB for example.

Comment: May be I am confused with block size and chunk size. I see this on FAQ page.

"I want to store large messages; what is the limit?
The limit is about 1 GB, as of Chronicle 4.x. The practical limit without tuning the configuration is about 16 MB. At this point you get significant inefficiencies, unless you increase the data allocation chunk size."

What is this 16 MB that we are referring to ?

Comment: Also, is there any performance impact if I change that to 1 GB, which I believe is the max that could be set ?

Comment: @AnirudhKashyap in the latest versions you can set the size to many GB. The main downside is; you can't use 4GB or more on windows, but you can on Linux and  how much apparent space you waste, though on Linux memory and disk are allocated lazily.

Comment: Thanks Peter. Can you also shed some light on chunk size and block size and let's say I specify my block size to be 100MB, I read that the max size for write should be not greater than 25 MB. Why is this the case ?

Comment: @AnirudhKashyap The chunks are allocated with overlapping regions.  This overlap is 25% of the chunk size. If you start writing near the end of a chunk, you can only write 25% in one go.  With lots of smaller writes you can write more an a chunk, but 25% is always safe.

Comment: Also, in the case where I can have varied sized messages being written, what is the best block size that needs to be set ? set it to max ?

Comment: This will be my last question. In my above example of 100MB block size and 25MB overlap size, will there be a 100 MB block allocated off heap and we keep writing chunks of max of 25 MB in that block ?

Comment: The first block allocated is 125% of the chunk size. e.g. the default is 64 MB but the file starts with 80 MB. Every time it grows by 64 MB.

Comment: Thanks a lot Peter, that helps.